# getting null when printing an image in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to pick an image from photo library and for that I used picker controller, but when I am trying to print the image in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method I am getting a `null` response. I used protocols also in my .h file.

```
- (IBAction)choosePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    NSLog(@"choose the img");
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];


}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

     self.imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
       NSLog(@"imgae is %@",self.imageView.image);
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    // here you can check that image is null or not
    [Btn_ImagePicker setImage:chosenImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

For the full detail kindly print `NSLog(@"%@",info);` info contains full details.